# Simple Test Website

Tags: html, css

Just want to know if I used CSS Grid properly along with flex. I always have that feeling that what I'm programming can look better and be shorter, etc. Thoughts?

```css
/* Main */ 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand');


body {
 background-color: #ecf0f1;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

.grid {
 display: grid;
 padding-bottom: 30px;
 grid-template-rows: auto auto;
 justify-content: space-around;
 grid-template-areas:
  ". . title . ."
  ". main main main ."
} 
 
.main {
 overflow: hidden;
 grid-area: main;
 display: inline-flex;
 
 margin: 150px 10px 10px 10px;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: row;
}

.site_header {
 overflow: hidden;
 position: fixed;
 grid-area: head;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 background-color: #2ecc71;
}



.site_header h1 {
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 50px;
 padding-right: 15px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 width: 300px;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
 border-radius: 0px 0px 60px 0px;
 background-color: beige;
}
.site_header a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #e74c3c;
}

.site_content {
 width: 1000px;
 height: 600px;
 background: #2ecc71;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}

.main_title {
 grid-area: title;
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #e74c3c;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 200px;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.75em;
}


.site_content p {
 color: black;
}

.site_aside {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-right: 50px;
 width: 200px;
 padding: 15px;
 background: lightblue; 
}

.site_footer {
 width: 98%;
 margin-left: 1%;
 justify-self: center;
 display: inline-flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: center;
 border-top: 4px solid #2ecc71;
}

.site_footer p {
 font-weight: bold;
}
 
.site_footer a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
 
.small {
 font-size: 0.75em;
 font-weight: lighter;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "styles/main.css">
  <title>New Wizardry Test page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <header class = "site_header">
    <h1><a href = "Test page .html">New Wizardry</a></h1><!--  nav bar will be located here -->
  </header>
  
  <div class = "grid">
   <div class = "main_title">
    <h1>Main Page</h1>
   </div>
   <div class = "main">
    <div class = "site_aside">
     Site aside
      
    </div>
    <div class = "site_content">
     
     <p>Here is where we will talk about what we do, updates, talk about the company(about us) etc.. either a progression bar or a launch date will be placed here.</p>
    </div>
    
    
   </div>
  </div>
  <footer class = "site_footer">
   <p>New Wizardry<span class= "small"> - A Front-end Programming company</span></p>
   <p>Email: <span class= "small"><a href = "mailto:sales@newWizardry.com"> sales@newwizardry.com</a></p>
   <p>Darcey McKelvey</p>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```